# jquery, on click anywhere inside div except certain child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following html

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="window"><!-- contents of window ---></div>
</div>
```

Parent is 100% width with padding top and bottom and Window is centered inside it with a width of 600px.

What I need to figure out is a jquery selector which will trigger when the user clicks anywhere that is inside of Parent but outside of Window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the target has id parent

```
$('#parent').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == "parent") {
        //code for clicking outside window but inside parent
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Cu28/1/)

Comment: Thanks, my needs have altered slightly since I asked the question but this was the beginnings of a workable answer and perfect for the original requirements.

Comment: I think it would It should but i cant check now since im on the phone :p @Jashwant

Comment: Actually, on a sibling the target would be sibling, so it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a click handler to `#parent` and then prevent propagation of clicks from `#window`. This allows you to have additional nested content inside of `#parent` without messing around with lists of the event targets.

```
$("#window").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("#parent").on("click", function(e) {
    // Do your thing
});
```

See a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/4kGJX/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
$('#parent').not("#window").on('click', function (e) {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: The result of the `#parent` selector will never contain `#window` so your `.not()` filter will have no effect.

Comment: `not` is not a child select but a `filter` function. This is gonna filter all elements with id `window` from the collection selected by `$('#parent')`